# Logistic Regression Class Imbalance and the use of weighting and undersampling

Tags: logistic, unbalanced-classes, rare-events, oversampling, spark-mllib

I have been working on a machine learning model using Spark (binomial) LogisticRegression. The dataset has what I think is a high degree of imbalance - roughly 1% of rows are labelled as events. The original author has used a [weightCol](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.html#setWeightCol-java.lang.String-) to try and improve the model. The weights used are the inverse of the prevalence of the label (so those labelled as events are given a weight of 0.99, those non-events are weighted 0.01). A side effect of this is that the predictions from the model are skewed. Without using the weighting column, the mean of the probabilities output for the test set is roughly 1%; but *with* the weighting column, the average probability is around 30%. Is this a even valid use of the weightCol?

I have been reading lots of other articles/questions and I'm not convinced either way...I gather that this concept of weighting might have come from [King and Zheng 2001](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/0s.pdf) which makes it sound like it's meant for correcting under/oversampling (e.g. my data set has 1% events but I know the real rate is 5%).

Is there a way to correct the skewed probabilities from using weighting in the manner I described? I only arrived at the paper I cited from trying to answer this very question; in the paper they propose that only the intercept needs adjusting and give a formula for doing so (one that my Stack Exchange skills - or lack thereof - prohibit me from listing, but you can see it in the first answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72944/can-logistic-regression-estimates-suffering-from-subsample-abuse-be-salvaged/72965#72965)). If the formula is even applicable in our case, for the weighting I described, the sample is weighted as 1 minus the actual weight anyway (this makes the log term evaluate to ln(1), which is 0, and so the intercept is unchanged!).

I was wondering if, with the weighting that has been applied, we have effectively evened out the samples and that the y-hat value I need to plug into the formula is 0.5 (like in the link, actually). But then it just feels like I'm making up my own values...hence my cry for help!

I think I understand how I could use that formula to correct for undersampling (by undersampling I mean using fewer non-events to make the events seem more prevalent), but I am less keen on this approach as when I tried it, the precision was adeversely affected (which makes sense to me as the model has been trained on fewer non-events).

I *have* been asking myself why people would implement ways to do under/oversampling and weighting in Spark, which both skew the probabilities,  without implementing a way to correct the probabilities (i.e. adjust the intercept). Maybe it's that they're both meant to be used together, and that weightCol is actually to correct for under/oversampling anyway?

Comment: 0. Welcome to the community. 1. Good on you for arriving at the King paper independently it is an interesting read. 2. Please see my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380577);it discusses how we would recalibrate the probabilities "*in the manner (similar to one you) described*", offers relevant references and highlights the case of screening vs. diagnosing which is very prevalent when dealing with rare event data.